# Facebook Payment In Android application

Tags: android, facebook, api, payment

Facebook is lunching Facebook Payment for their canvas application. I have requirement to integrate facebook payment for my android application as well. I explore about it but did not find any useful link

Any any body tell me if Facebook Payments are also available for android ? If yes can I have a useful link for integration it in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this link: http://www.facebook.com/help/172290966189492 you can't.
You will have to put a `WebView` in your native Android and do the buying from there.